# Concat two datetime indexed Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, concatenation

I am having a problem concating two Dataframes without loosing the date time index.

df1:

```
DateTime             Open     High     Low      Close              
2022-09-22 09:19:00  143.562  143.619  143.227  143.246
```

df2:

```
DateTime             Open     High     Low      Close              
2022-09-22 09:20:00  143.660  143.702  143.367  143.355
```

I am trying to concat with following code:

```
combined_data = pd.concat([previous_df, df_test], axis=0)
```

when I try and use concat I get following output:

```
    Unnamed: 0  DateTime    Open    High    Low Close
    1   1   2022-09-22 09:19:00 NaN 143.562 143.619 143.227 143.246
    2   2022-09-22 09:20:00 NaN NaN 143.098 143.098 142.683 142.698
```

So now every single Datetime index is created as a new index

I have also tried using join = inner/outer with the same results.
Using ignore_index = true/false has the same results

EDIT TO QUESTION:

I found out that the problem exists because df1 is loaded from a csv and either while saving to the csv or loading from csv the index gets lost.

The question now is only how I can save and load the index correctly from a csv.

code for saving to csv:

df.to_csv('datatest.csv')

code for loading from csv:

```
previous_df = pd.read_csv('datatest.csv')

combined_data = pd.concat([previous_df, df_test], axis=0)

combined_data
```

Comment: Does this code give the output you want ?: `combined_data=combined_data.set_index('DateTime')`

Comment: Unfortunately not this give me the KeyError: Datetime

Comment: @NikolasWeichert what is your index in your previous_df and previous_df dataframes? i have check with your data and should be ok.

Comment: I have to update the Question because the problem did not arise from the code posted here. 
The Problem is that df1 is a data frame derived from a csv, while df2 is downloaded via yfinance. 
YFinance sets the index as date time while the index loaded from the csv apparently is unnamed: 0 
I am currently trying to figure out how to "save" the index when Saving data to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem arose from reading the csv. Csv did not save index correctly and renamed it to unnamed which is why the two df were not able to concat correctly